# CodeIgniter: Update public variable in MY_Controller from model

Tags: php, codeigniter, this, codeigniter-2

I am working on a project with **CodeIgniter**. I extended CI's base Controller class with a custom MY_Controller. MY_Controller has a authentication flag variable `$auth = FALSE`. On pages that require authentication, I call my `auth_model->runAuth()` function to run checks and this flag should be updated to `TRUE` if all checks pass. For some reason I can't update my `$auth` variable in MY_Controller directly from the auth_model with `$this->auth = TRUE`, but I have to pass the check result back to the page controller first and then update the `$auth` variable in MY_Controller. Any ideas how to update the `$auth` flag in MY_Controller directly from the model without going through a controller? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Update: The $auth variable in MY_Controller is public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to assign the flag directly via the method call like this

```
$this->auth = $this->auth_model->runAuth();
```

In the MY_Controller class! The method `runAuth()` does not need a big change:

Instead of calling `$auth = TRUE` or `FALSE`, just return true or false like this:

```
public function runAuth()
{
    // do stuff
    return true; // or false depending on success.
}
```

Hope that helps. Otherwise you would need a refernce to the MY_Controller object somehow. For Example:

```
$this->auth_model->runAuth($this);
```

Now in your method:

```
public function runAuth(MY_Controller $myctrl)
{
    // do stuff
    $myctrl->auth = true; // or false

}
```

Another option would be to use static fields:

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller
{
    public static $auth = false;
    // the other stuff
}
```

Now you can update this without an object refernce:

```
public function runAuth()
{
    // do stuff
    MY_Controller::$auth = true;
}
```

In your models you can access it like this:

```
if (static::$auth) echo "Boo Yeah!";
```

Comment: Thanks very much Christian for your help. I went with your first option to assign the result directly via $this->auth. But it's very helpful to know a couple of other options as well. Thanks again! (Grüsse aus Raleigh nach Hamburg)

Comment: PS: Calling the variable's status using static::$auth (last or your options) worked fine in controllers and models, but not in views directly. Hence my decision to go with option A. Cheers.

Comment: From the view you have to call at again this way: `MY_Controller::$auth`! (Viele Grüße zurück :D)